# Do WSGI servers connect to devices outside of the network?

Tags: python, flask, wsgi, waitress

I want to set up a plotly dashboard and view it from my browser.

Plotly gets set up as a flask application. I'm of the understanding that I should use a WSGI server to host it. I'm looking at [waitress](https://pypi.org/project/waitress/) in particular.

Does waitress, or WSGI servers in general, connect to devices outside of the network? In other words, if I have a dashboard, will all the data and charts and other details about the dashboard stay local to my machine?

Comment: run it with `serve(wsgiapp, host='127.0.0.1', port=8080)` In particular, that `host='127.0.0.1'`. You define what IPs/ports your service listens on. To listen on an interface is to accept connects from there. Even if you ran it with `host='0.0.0.0'` (this means all interfaces) you're still likely behind a NAT so only devices on the local network could connect to you.

Comment: I disagree with the reason it was closed. My question is about whether data stays on my local machine whereas the question linked in the closure is about setting up a production server

Comment: You can likely make the assumption that unless you've specifically put code in that makes requests out to other places, nothing is connecting out or sending data out. It's an impossible question to answer absolutely though because it depends on the entirety of the code and libraries you're running. Often a problem like this is handled at more of a firewall level where you would disallow any outbound connections.